# ASP.NET : Form posting via jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an ASP.NET page with 2 ASP.NET text boxes and one ASP.NET drop downlist I want toi use jQuery form posting instead of normal ASP.NET post back.Can anyone guide me how to do this ? How can i access the server side controls in the action page ? I dont want to pass everything via query string. Kindly guide me how to go ahead ? Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to post it with ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use simple jQuery selectors to select Server Side Controls suppose you have following textbox on your page:

```
<asp:TextBox id="userName" runat="server" />
```

in jQuery you can access it like this:

```
var valueOfTextBox = $("input[id$='userName']").val();
//OR
var valueOfTextBox = $("input[id$='userName']").attr("value");
```

if you have few controls on page then this technique is okay but for large forms please use this instead:

```
var valueOfTextBox = $("#<%= userName.ClientID %>").val();
//OR
var valueOfTextBox = $("#<%= userName.ClientID %>").attr("value");
```

There is huge performance gain, as explained by Dave [here](http://encosia.com/2009/06/09/11-keystrokes-that-made-my-jquery-selector-run-10x-faster/).

You can find more about jQuery selector syntax [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

If you want to post form via jquery AJAX then use this code:

```
  $("#form1").submit(function(){//Where form1 is your form's id
    var a=$("input[id$='userName']").val();
    var b=$("input[id$='userId']").val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "yourPage.aspx",
       data: "name=" + a+"&id=" + b,
       success: function(msg){
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       }
     });
  });
```

More details about jQuery AJAX are [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).

You can also use [jquery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin to automate the things.